# Is Bloomfilter one way hash?

Tags: bloom-filter

I am planning to distribute a bloomfilter through S3 for one of client application. There are couple of options I can take here.

1. Allow client to download the file directly from S3 through a pre-signed URL.
2. Respond the whole bloomfilter content to Client via API response.

Can someone please point to the documentation which explains about Bloomfilter decoding or decrypting? Can any decode the Bloomfilter and get the data back if they have access to Bloomfilter file or is it one way hashing?

Thanks,
Hareesh

Answer (score 0):

Bloom filters do not decode or decrypt.

Bloom filers are a fast way to tell if a key is in a set, with the special property that they return false positives but no false negatives.

This picture explains this very well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#/media/File:Bloom_filter_speed.svg